# javascript stopPropagation() prevents function from firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, stoppropagation

I have a child div with class `body_left_details` which resides in a parent div with class `body_left_bar`.  Both divs have an onclick event attached to them, but I want to prevent the bubbling of `body_left_bar` when you click on `body_left_details`.  Here's the relevant code:

```
$(function() {
    $('.body_left_bar').click(function() {
        body_right_load('parent');
    })
    $('.body_left_details').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        body_right_load('child');
    })
})
function body_right_load(str) {
    alert(str);
}​
```

Simple enough.  But why is it that when I click on `body_left_details`, body_right_load('child') is not called?  I tested with an alert() directly after e.stopPropagation(), and it worked fine.  Are external functions not allowed after stopPropagation?  Would that be considered bubbling?

Testing on Windows 7 wamp in Chrome.  Any insight appreciated!

EDIT: [Relevant jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/teGPX/2/).  Clicking on parent div will result in alert, but clicking on "Read about it" yields nothing.

Comment: It probably has to do with the way `body_right_load()` is *really* declared.  If it really looked like what you've posted, it would work.

Comment: Please provide a fiddle that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Indeed I have dumbed the general layout down slightly, but I have changed body_right_load to show as above and still doesn't fire.  Give me a minute for fiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nqFH4/ works like a charm.

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: aid is not defined` (line ~38)

Comment: Yea, laziness got the best of me.  Didn't clean it up fully, sorry.  It seems like Wade's is working on fiddle, but we'll see in production.  If you want to post an answer of a kind I'll throw out some upvotes.

Comment: Your fiddle, with the errors fixed (and `.click()`) [works fine.](http://jsfiddle.net/teGPX/3/)

Comment: Touche, @Pointy.  You are correct.  .click() and .on() give same result.  I guess you guys forced me to fix some small error elsewhere while trying to figure this out.  Champagne for everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('.body_left_bar').on('click', function() {
        body_right_load('parent');
    })
    $('.body_left_details').on('click', function(e) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        body_right_load('child');
    })
})
function body_right_load(str) {
    alert(str);
}​
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/ ". A handler can prevent the event from bubbling further up the document tree (and thus prevent handlers on those elements from running) by calling event.stopPropagation(). Any other handlers attached on the current element will run however. To prevent that, call event.stopImmediatePropagation(). (Event handlers bound to an element are called in the same order that they were bound.)"

Comment: I ask again, how would that differ from original posted code? There are no more than 1 event attatched to `.body_left_details`, so using `stopImmediatePropagation` should not differ form `stopPropagation`, except (and I'm not sure about this) it would seem (from your pasted docs) that `stopImmediatePropagation` would still run the click-event on the parent element (in other words, it propagates, just not to handlers on the same element), but I might be wrong on that point.

Comment: Bravo @Wade, it seems you have cracked the code!  stopImmediatePropagation achieved same as stopPropagation, but using "on" seems to have solved it.  Thanks!

Comment: The change from `.click()` to `.on()` makes no difference.  The code as posted in the fiddle by the OP already works (once the obvious irrelevant errors are fixed).